# Angular call a calculated variable in another function within a loop

Tags: angular, loops, variables

I'm learning Angular 5 and am used to PHP so variables are confusing me.

I have a loop and want to call a calculated variable in another function within a loop. My code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
  <td>
  {{item > 0 ? myNewVar = 1 : myNewVar = 0}} // Why can't I do this?
  {{myNewVar}}
  </td>
  <td>
  {{myFunc(myNewVar)}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Angular is complaining thusly about my code above:

> Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column

Why can't I declare a variable in an if statement within a template?  Do I need to do everything within functions?

Comment: You're probably better off moving the logic to the component class. You could also  add properties like `myNewVar` and `myFuncVal` to each `item` beforehand in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this. For details, look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mabo8d)

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
    <td>
    {{myFunc2(item)}}
    </td>
    <td>
    {{myFunc(myNewVar)}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Harunur, unfortunately I'm still getting "Bindings cannot contain assignments" in the console with that cod.e

Comment: @RyanDorn, updated my answer. Hope this will work as you are expecting.